# Proxifier disables MetroStyle apps Internet Connection

Tags: proxy, windows-8-preview, socks-proxy

I'm using Windows 8 release preview. When I install Proxifier (to set my SOCKS proxy), none of my MetroStyle apps can access the Internet (even the ones I develop). So, my question is, is there a way to fix this? Either by setting a proxy for all my MetroStyle apps or making them access the Internet directly. It's frustrating. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20151204091513/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/fiddler/archive/2011/12/10/fiddler-windows-8-apps-enable-loopback-network-isolation-exemption.aspx).

Metrostyle apps are not allowed to have a loopback connection by default.You should use his software to enable that.

Comment: I downloaded the app, checked all the apps and clicked `Save Changes` but it didn't work. What else should I do? Thanks.

Comment: It did work for me, although i was using it with a local http proxy and not a SOCKS proxy. Try to see if you can capture their data using fiddler.

Comment: OK. Thanks. When I started fiddler, everything worked as expected. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have created a step-by-step blog post for other users. Here's the link: http://www.alireza-noori.com/general/how-to-use-proxifier-for-windows-8-metrostyle-apps/

Comment: Here's the new link http://anoori.me/blog/general/use-proxifier-in-windows-8-without-fiddler2

Answer (score 0):

From the brief description of how Proxifier works, no, it won't work from Windows 8 Metro applications. It's very likely implemented as a Winsock LSP, and those aren't loaded by apps running in AppContainers. To do something like that, you need to use an updated product implemented on top of the Windows Filtering Platform (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks. But is there **any** way I can use MetroStyle apps when I install Proxifier? Or is there an alternative to this app?